# grunt-contrib-watch not calling task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have grunt-contrib-watch configured like this:

```
watch: {
    tasks: ['copyFiles'],
    js: {
        files: [
            path.join(__dirname, "../gscm-js/src/**/*.js"),
            path.join(__dirname, "../gscm-js/templates/**/*.*")]
    },
    options: {
        debounceDelay: 250,
    }
}
```

And I have my `copyFiles` task looking like this;

```
grunt.registerTask('copyFiles', 'copy templates and js', function () {
    console.log('in copyFiles');
    var done = this.async();

    var sourceScripts = path.join(__dirname, "../gscm-js/src");
    var sourceTemplates = path.join(__dirname, "../gscm-js/templates");

    ncp(sourceScripts, scriptsDirectory, function () {
        ncp(sourceTemplates, templatesDirectory, done);
    });
});
```

BUt the log message is never outputted to the console even though the watch task outputs that a file has changed.

Answer (score 0):

`grunt-contrib-watch` is a Grunt multi-task, and `js` is the name of one of its multiple tasks.

You need to move the `tasks` configuration setting into the `js` task:

```
watch: {
    js: {
        files: [
            path.join(__dirname, "../gscm-js/src/**/*.js"),
            path.join(__dirname, "../gscm-js/templates/**/*.*")
        ],
        tasks: ['copyFiles']
    },
    options: {
        debounceDelay: 250
    }
}
```

`options` can remain where it is - it's given special treatment and is shared between multiple tasks.